# DIALOGUE INC PenMount USB caused Xorg Segmentation fault

Tags: ubuntu, segmentation-fault, logout, xorg

After my xubuntu 16.04 logout unexpected. I found Segmentation fault messages from `Xorg.0.log.old`

The backtrace:

```
[ 16577.473] (EE) 
[ 16577.473] (EE) Backtrace:
[ 16577.474] (EE) 0: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (xorg_backtrace+0x4e) [0x56163ec3df7e]
[ 16577.474] (EE) 1: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x56163ea8c000+0x1b5ce9) [0x56163ec41ce9]
[ 16577.474] (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x7f3021e9f000+0x11390) [0x7f3021eb0390]
[ 16577.474] (EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (GetMaster+0x68) [0x56163ead7348]
[ 16577.474] (EE) 4: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (IsFloating+0x1c) [0x56163eae852c]
[ 16577.475] (EE) 5: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (GetPairedDevice+0x28) [0x56163ead9378]
[ 16577.475] (EE) 6: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (IsFloating+0x1c) [0x56163eae852c]
[ 16577.475] (EE) 7: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (GetPairedDevice+0x28) [0x56163ead9378]
[ 16577.475] (EE) 8: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (IsFloating+0x1c) [0x56163eae852c]
[ 16577.475] (EE) 9: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (GetPairedDevice+0x28) [0x56163ead9378]
[ 16577.475] (EE) 10: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (IsFloating+0x1c) [0x56163eae852c]
[ 16577.475] (EE) 11: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (GetPairedDevice+0x28) [0x56163ead9378]
[ 16577.475] (EE) 12: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (IsFloating+0x1c) [0x56163eae852c]
[ 16577.475] (EE) 13: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (miPointerGetScreen+0x9) [0x56163ec2a0e9]
[ 16577.475] (EE) 14: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (xf86PostButtonEventM+0x3f) [0x56163eb3025f]
[ 16577.476] (EE) 15: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (xf86PostButtonEvent+0xdd) [0x56163eb3039d]
[ 16577.476] (EE) 16: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/penmount_drv.so (0x7f301968b000+0x5914) [0x7f3019690914]
[ 16577.476] (EE) 17: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x7f3021e9f000+0x11390) [0x7f3021eb0390]
[ 16577.476] (EE) 18: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (epoll_wait+0x33) [0x7f3021bdc9d3]
[ 16577.476] (EE) 19: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x56163ea8c000+0x1b6774) [0x56163ec42774]
[ 16577.476] (EE) 20: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (WaitForSomething+0x1d3) [0x56163ec3b963]
[ 16577.476] (EE) 21: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x56163ea8c000+0x540a1) [0x56163eae00a1]
[ 16577.476] (EE) 22: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x56163ea8c000+0x58398) [0x56163eae4398]
[ 16577.476] (EE) 23: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf0) [0x7f3021af5830]
[ 16577.477] (EE) 24: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (_start+0x29) [0x56163eace329]
[ 16577.477] (EE) 
[ 16577.477] (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0xd7
[ 16577.477] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[ 16577.477] (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
[ 16577.477] (EE) 
[ 16577.477] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[ 16577.477] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[ 16577.477] (EE) 
[ 16577.478] (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
[ 16577.543] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

At time of `12218.324`, PENMOUNT USB `Removed` and plugined immediately(6 seconds).

```
[    29.735] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1440x900"x0.0  106.50  1440 1520 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync (55.9 kHz e)
[    29.735] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1600x1200"x0.0  162.00  1600 1664 1856 2160  1200 1201 1204 1250 +hsync +vsync (75.0 kHz e)
[    29.735] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x0.0  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync (65.3 kHz e)
[    29.735] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x60.0  172.80  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118 -hsync +vsync (67.1 kHz e)
[ 12218.324] (II) [PENMOUNT (10)] Device Removed !
[ 12218.329] (II) config/udev: removing device DIALOGUE INC PenMount USB
[ 12218.353] (II) UnloadModule: "penmount"
[ 12218.353] (II) [PENMOUNT (0)] PenMount Module Unloaded !
[ 12224.003] (II) config/udev: Adding input device DIALOGUE INC PenMount USB (/dev/input/mouse0)
[ 12224.004] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 12224.004] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 12224.102] (II) config/udev: Adding input device DIALOGUE INC PenMount USB (/dev/input/event3)
[ 12224.102] (**) DIALOGUE INC PenMount USB: Applying InputClass "evdev touchscreen catchall"
[ 12224.102] (**) DIALOGUE INC PenMount USB: Applying InputClass "Penmount Touch Screen"
[ 12224.102] (**) DIALOGUE INC PenMount USB: Applying InputClass "Penmount Touch Screen"
[ 12224.102] (II) Using input driver 'penmount' for 'DIALOGUE INC PenMount USB'
[ 12224.102] (**) DIALOGUE INC PenMount USB: always reports core events
[ 12224.102] (**) Option "DeviceType" "2"
[ 12224.102] (**) Option "DebugLevel" "0"
[ 12224.102] (**) Option "RandR" "0"
[ 12224.102] (**) Option "ADBit" "10"
[ 12224.103] (**) Option "SuppDClickTime" "800"
[ 12224.103] (**) Option "EnableTX" "1"
[ 12224.103] (**) Option "JitterFilter" "8"
[ 12224.103] (**) Option "Monitor" "default"
[ 12224.103] (**) Option "ConfigFile" "/etc/penmount/penmount.dat"
[ 12224.103] (**) Option "UseEEPROM" "1"
```

So i checked the `Xorg.0.log`(Xorg restart and started a new log). I can tell now Xorg crashed at `Fri Jun  9 15:37:21 2023`

```
[ 16577.884]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[ 16577.884] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[ 16577.885] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Jun  9 15:37:21 2023
[ 16577.885] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
```

Then, `/var/log/kern.log` shows that PenMount USB disconnect and connect again in 5 seconds

```
Jun  9 14:24:41 aubo-4250301418 kernel: [12218.302648] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 2
Jun  9 14:24:41 aubo-4250301418 kernel: [12218.302670] usb 1-3.1: USB disconnect, device number 4
Jun  9 14:24:46 aubo-4250301418 kernel: [12223.292213] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
Jun  9 14:24:46 aubo-4250301418 kernel: [12223.440521] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=2512
Jun  9 14:24:46 aubo-4250301418 kernel: [12223.440537] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
Jun  9 14:24:46 aubo-4250301418 kernel: [12223.442385] hub 1-3:1.0: USB hub found
Jun  9 14:24:46 aubo-4250301418 kernel: [12223.442569] hub 1-3:1.0: 2 ports detected
Jun  9 14:24:46 aubo-4250301418 kernel: [12223.732187] usb 1-3.1: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
Jun  9 14:24:47 aubo-4250301418 kernel: [12223.835784] usb 1-3.1: New USB device found, idVendor=14e1, idProduct=6000
Jun  9 14:24:47 aubo-4250301418 kernel: [12223.835800] usb 1-3.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jun  9 14:24:47 aubo-4250301418 kernel: [12223.835809] usb 1-3.1: Product: PenMount USB
Jun  9 14:24:47 aubo-4250301418 kernel: [12223.835817] usb 1-3.1: Manufacturer: DIALOGUE INC
Jun  9 14:24:47 aubo-4250301418 kernel: [12223.843886] input: DIALOGUE INC PenMount USB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.1/1-3.1:1.0/0003:14E1:6000.0002/input/input8
Jun  9 14:24:47 aubo-4250301418 kernel: [12223.844468] hid-penmount 0003:14E1:6000.0002: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.01 Mouse [DIALOGUE INC PenMount USB] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3.1/input0
Jun  9 14:25:00 aubo-4250301418 kernel: [12236.960808] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 5
Jun  9 14:25:00 aubo-4250301418 kernel: [12236.960832] usb 1-3.1: USB disconnect, device number 6
Jun  9 14:25:03 aubo-4250301418 kernel: [12240.264205] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
Jun  9 14:25:03 aubo-4250301418 kernel: [12240.412608] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=2512
Jun  9 14:25:03 aubo-4250301418 kernel: [12240.412628] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
Jun  9 14:25:03 aubo-4250301418 kernel: [12240.415341] hub 1-3:1.0: USB hub found
Jun  9 14:25:03 aubo-4250301418 kernel: [12240.415522] hub 1-3:1.0: 2 ports detected
Jun  9 14:25:03 aubo-4250301418 kernel: [12240.708144] usb 1-3.1: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
Jun  9 14:25:04 aubo-4250301418 kernel: [12240.811665] usb 1-3.1: New USB device found, idVendor=14e1, idProduct=6000
Jun  9 14:25:04 aubo-4250301418 kernel: [12240.811686] usb 1-3.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jun  9 14:25:04 aubo-4250301418 kernel: [12240.811698] usb 1-3.1: Product: PenMount USB
Jun  9 14:25:04 aubo-4250301418 kernel: [12240.811709] usb 1-3.1: Manufacturer: DIALOGUE INC
Jun  9 14:25:04 aubo-4250301418 kernel: [12240.827418] input: DIALOGUE INC PenMount USB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.1/1-3.1:1.0/0003:14E1:6000.0003/input/input9
Jun  9 14:25:04 aubo-4250301418 kernel: [12240.888690] hid-penmount 0003:14E1:6000.0003: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.01 Mouse [DIALOGUE INC PenMount USB] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3.1/input0
```

Thank you so much if someone can help. :)

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a bug of PenMount USB driver. After i got contact with the manufacture and report this bug, they send me a newer version of driver package and the bug was FIXED.